# Two different classes in Angular component

Tags: angular

Let's say I have an `HTML` component that looks something like this:

```
<div class="avatar">Some name</div>
```

The SCSS component looks like this:

```
.avatar {
  height: 60px;
  width: 60px;

  &.small {
    height: 40px;
    width: 40px;
  }
}
```

The `ts` component is just something like:

```
import { Component, OnInit, Input } from '@angular/core';

@Component({
  selector: 'lqs-avatar',
  templateUrl: './avatar.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./avatar.component.scss']
})
export class AvatarComponent implements OnInit {

  constructor() { }

  ngOnInit() {

  }

}
```

And when I use the component in some other place I just do e.g.:

```
<lqs-avatar></lqs-avatar>
```

So my question is: How can I make it so that I can alter between the normal avatar size and the small size (i.e. changing the class) ?

I mean, I could just create a small avatar component, but that seems a bit overkill. Shouldn't I be able to just say something like:

```
<lqs-avatar size="small"></lqs-avatar>
```

and then it adds small to the class or something like that ?

Comment: You can do it like in your example - you can read about angular @Input()
https://angular.io/guide/inputs-outputs. 

Short version: you pass param like 'size' to the component and inside depending on this parameter add small class to avatar.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can add an `Input()` to your component, this will allow you to pass data to your component from a parent component. You can also take this into account when using a name like between your `div` tags.

Your component would look like this:

**Note:** I added a `large` size to show more of what can be done. You either need to add the css or remove `large` from the ts/html logic.

```js
@Component({
  selector: 'lqs-avatar',
  templateUrl: './avatar.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./avatar.component.scss']
})
export class AvatarComponent implements OnInit {

  @Input() size: 'small' | 'medium' | 'large' = 'medium'
  @Input() name = ''

}
```

The template would then have an `ngClass` which you can then toggle the class on the div based on the `size` input value.

```html
<!-- No need to test for medium because it is the default style -->
<div class="avatar" [ngClass]="{
  small: size === 'small',
  large: size === 'large'
}">
  {{name}}
</div>
```

Lastly, you would then call the component from within another component:

```html
<!-- The following two are for medium/default size -->
<lqs-avatar></lqs-avatar>
<lqs-avatar size="medium"></lqs-avatar>

<!-- This one is for a large size avatar -->
<lqs-avatar size="large"></lqs-avatar>

<!-- This one is for a small size avatar -->
<lqs-avatar size="small"></lqs-avatar>

<!-- Set a size and name -->
<lqs-avatar size="small" name="Billy Joe"></lqs-avatar>

<!-- Loop over an array of users with avatars -->
<lqs-avatar *ngFor="let user of users" size="small" [name]="user.name"></lqs-avatar>
```

Answer (score 1):

Yes, you need to use the `@Input()` decorator on `AvatarComponent`.

```
import { Component, OnInit, Input } from '@angular/core';

@Component({
  selector: 'lqs-avatar',
  templateUrl: './avatar.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./avatar.component.scss']
})
export class AvatarComponent implements OnInit {
  @Input() size: string;
  constructor() { }

  ngOnInit() {

  }

}

// HTML
<div [ngClass]="['avatar', size]">Some name</div>

// To use
<lqs-avatar size="small"></lqs-avatar> (1)
// Or
<lqs-avatar [size]="'small'"></lqs-avatar> (2)
// The first way is the preferred way if the `small` string will never change
```